# Unrecognized manifest key 'icon'. Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

i am writing a simple hello world extension in chrome although it loads but why does it gives me a warning. Also the extension logo is not present.
My images is present in the same directory as my working directory.

[image]

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name": "Hello World",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "description" : "A hello world Extension",
    "icon" : {
        "128": "128icon.png",
        "48" : "48icon.png",
        "16" : "16icon.png"
    },


    "browser_action":{
        "default_icon": "16icon.png",
        "default_popup" : "popup.html"

    }


}
```

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest): it should be `icons`.

Comment: @wOxxOm, why don't you add that as an answer?

Comment: Because it looks like a typo question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `"icon"` with `"icons"`